# In Netlogo, is there a way to ask a patch to hatch a turtle?

Tags: netlogo

I'm trying to make a public transportation model, and I want turtles to hatch from specific patch types at certain schedules

```
Ask patches with house [
create-traveler household-size [
   setxy pxcor pycor
   set color black
   set shape "people"

]
]
```

Also is there a way to spawn turtles over a range of patch values? I want to spawn turtles along side a street, the street is down the middle of the world north to south and is 4 patches wide, I want to spawn turtles on random xcor but a ycor that is greater than 2 or less than -2 and not greater than 3 or less than -3.

I'm just not sure how to handle this because the patches cannot use turtle context methods.

Answer (score 2):

There are three different primitives that allow you to create turtles:

- `create-turtles`: is used in observer context. It creates one or more turtles in the origin, at patch 0 0.
- `hatch`: is used in turtle context. The newly created turtle inherits all proporties from its parent turtle, except the who and the properties specified during this procedure.
- `sprout`: is used in patch context. It creates one or more turtles in the patch that called it. This creates the turtle in the center of the patch.

All three of these procedures also have a breedspecific alternative. In your case that would be: `create-traveler`, `hatch-traveler`, and `sprout-traveler`.

You could also just create the turtles normally and then move them to the patches where you want them immediately afterwards. The example below gives you a set of 1000 turtles that are standing alongside the road you specified.
You'll notice that instead of `setxy`, I `set xcor` and `set ycor` separately because I use different conditions for them (this could still quite easily be combined into a single `setxy` but I feel like it is more intuitive to split them up in this case).

```
create-turtles 1000 [
   set xcor random-xcor
   ifelse random-float 1 < 0.5 [set ycor random-float 1 + 2] [set ycor - 1 * (random-float 1 + 2)]
]
```

Finally, you could also use sprout for this as well. Notice how I use `repeat 1000`, `one-of patches`, and `sprout 1`. That means I sprout a total of 1000 turtles, randomly distributed over all the patches I want them on, one at a time. You will also notice that in this example, the turtles look at lot more neatly arranged, since all of them are sprouted in the center of their patch.

```
repeat 1000 [ 
   ask one-of patches with [pycor = -2 or pycor = 2] [
       sprout 1
   ]     
]
```

You can add some minor jitter to it if you want to (`setxy pxcor pxcor - 0.5 + random-float 1 pycor - 0.5 + random-float 1`) but of course that changes their coordinates so make sure that the jitter does not move them out of bounds (The jitter above would put them on the streets).