# Turtles randomly walking in specific area

Tags: netlogo

Hi I would like to hatch turtles at random patches but confined within a specific area.

```
 ask employees [
   set shape "person"
   set size 1.5
   set color blue
   setxy random-xcor random-ycor ]
```

How do I adjust the `setxy` line to force the turtles to all be confined to: `[ pxcor <= 8 and pxcor >= -8 and pycor <= 8 and pycor >= -8 ]`

Comment: I'm gonna refer you to a very similar question from two weeks ago https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74167366/in-netlogo-is-there-a-way-to-ask-a-patch-to-hatch-a-turtle/74180415#74180415

Answer (score 1):

After looking through various bits of different code, what I've done is:

```
globals [office-space]
  
set office-space patches with [ pxcor <= 8 and pxcor >= -8 and pycor <= 8 and pycor >= -8 ]

ask office-space [ set pcolor grey]
```

```
place-on-color-employees
```

```
to place-on-color-employees 
  let _patches (patches with [pcolor = grey])
  ask employees [
    move-to one-of (_patches with [not any? turtles-here])
  ]
end
```

Comment: You can accept your own answer in order to close the question

Comment: You define an agent set "office-space" then color it grey then use the color to find it again.  I think you could simply move-to one-of ( office-space with ...)